# Error Uncaught TypeError: PDOStatement::bindParam(): Argument #3

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

Hoy vengo con una nueva duda respecto a una consulta en MYSQL ya que estoy recibiendo un error de respuesta que me ha molado la cabeza.
**Contexto:**
Estoy construyendo un sistema de reseñas, y estoy en la parte de borrar la reseña, como no hay login necesitaba un método para validar que la persona que escribió esa reseña sea la misma que intenta borrar, la solución fue que al rescribir la reseña se le solicita a la personas escribir un correo electrónico y se guarda en la base de datos asociado al id de la reseña( solo se permite 1 por correo), con esto si alguien desea elimiar la reseña, debe escribir el correo con el cual hizo el comentario.

Llamado del boton eliminar:

Con este código obtengo el id de la reseña y abro un modal llamado verify donde la persona debe escribir el correo para validar si le pertenece o no esta reseña.

```html
<span data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#verify_modal"  onclick="DeleteUser(<?php echo $rws['review_id'];?>)"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></a>Delete</span>
```

El modal de verificación:

Aquí recibo el id de la reseña y el usuario debe escribir el correo exacto con el cual fue publicada la reseña y envio todo por ajax al archivo verify.php

```html
<!---verify modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="verify_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> 
        <h5 class="modal-title">One more step before editing</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="false">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <label for="email">Before you can edit, we need to verify if was you who wrote the review, please enter your email and press verify</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rws['review_id']; ?>">
       
            <input type="text" name="u_email" id="u_email" class="form-control" placeholder="your-mail@domain.com" required /> 
    <span id="review_id"></span>
      </div>
      <span id="verification-result"></span>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit"  name="validate" id="validate" class="btn btn-primary">Verify</button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El ajax que estoy usando:

```js
function DeleteUser(deleteid){
    $('#validate').click(function() {
    var emailDelete= $('#u_email').val();
    console.log(deleteid),
    console.log(emailDelete),
    $.ajax({
        url:'delete.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            deletesend:deleteid,
            u_email:emailDelete,
        },
        
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
            if(result = "No Found") {
               $('#verification-result').html("<span style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>You can not delete this review, Reason: The email address entered does not match with our records.</span>");
                          
            } else {
              $('#verification-result').html("<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>Are you sure you want to delete this review? <a href='' >Click here to delete</a>.</span>"); //en esta ancla debería crear el boton de confirmar el borrado en caso de que el correo y el id correspondan
            }
        
    }
    
});
})
}
```

Ahora se viene el archivo delete.php

aquí me aseguro que recibo los dos valores que he enviado a través de ajax para la consulta y es aquí donde recibo el error.

```php
<?php 
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/conexion.php");
$lang="es"; // Estas variables las coloco acá per vienen de un archivo global
$page_name="avatrade"; // Estas variables las coloco acá per vienen de un archivo global

if(isset($_POST['deletesend']) && isset($_POST['u_email'])){
    $unique=$_POST['deletesend'];
    $email =$_POST['u_email'];
    
    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) from avatrade WHERE review_id=? AND lang=? AND page_name=? AND user_email=? ";
    $stmt =$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt ->bindParam('isss',$unique, $lang, $page_name, $email, );
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($count > 0) {
        $result = "Found";
    } else {
        $result = "Not Found";
    }
    return $result; // regreso una variable con el valor Foun o No found para dterminar en AJAX que procede

}
?>
```

Este es el error que recibo

````
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\easycryptos\public_html\sitios\brokers-regulados\avatrade\reviews\delete.php(12): PDOStatement-&gt;bindParam('isss', '70', 'es', 'avatrade', 'palmiflor56@gma...')
#1 {main}
thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\easycryptos\public_html\sitios\brokers-regulados\avatrade\reviews\delete.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />```

De ante mano muchas gracias por su colaboración, No sé de donde puede venir el error.
ANOTACION: con este código sin importar si el correo es o no el usado para escribir la reseña obtengo el resultado "You can not delete this review, Reason: The email address entered does not match with our records", y leí en un foro que si algo está mal en la consulta siempre va a devolver false.
````

Comment: ¿No será que tiene una coma de más al final de la lista de parámetros después del *$email*?: `$stmt ->bindParam('isss',$unique, $lang, $page_name, $email, );`.  Quítala a ver si era eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno despues de leer muchas horas de documentación pude solucionar de esta manera. en el verify.php

```php
$lang="es"; //variables vienen de otro archivo global
$page_name="avatrade"; //variables vienen de otro archivo global

if(isset($_POST['verifysend']) && isset($_POST['u_email'])){
    $unique=$_POST['verifysend'];
    $email =$_POST['u_email'];
    
    $sql="SELECT * from avatrade WHERE review_id=:id AND lang=:lang AND page_name=:pag_name AND user_email=:mail ";
    $stmt =$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':id',$unique, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':lang',$lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':pag_name',$page_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt ->bindParam(':mail',$email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        
     $result = $count;
           
     echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Y en ajax tenía un error me faltaba un =, tenía en mi código "`if(data = "0")`" y me funcionó agregando "`if(data == "0")`"

```js
function DeleteUser(deleteid){
    $('#validate').click(function() {
    var emailDelete= $('#u_email').val();
    console.log(deleteid),
    console.log(emailDelete),
    $.ajax({
        url:'delete.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            deletesend:deleteid,
            u_email:emailDelete,
        },
        
    success: function(data){
        //console.log(data);
           if(data == "0") {
               $('#verification-result').html("<span style='color:red; text-align:justify; font-weight:bold;'>You ain't allowed to delete this review, Reason: The email address entered does not match with our records.</span>");
              //$('#verify_modal').modal('hide');
                          
            } else {
              $('#verification-result').html("<span style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>Are you sure you want to delete this review? <button type='submit'  name='confirm' id='confirm' class='btn btn-danger'>Confirm Delete</button></span>");
              $('#confirm').click(function() {
                  //console.log(deleteid),
                  //console.log(emailDelete),
                  $.ajax({
                  url:'delete.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data:{
                erasesend:deleteid,
                the_email:emailDelete,
                
                },
                  //sucess
                  })
                })
            }   
        }
    });
   })
}
```

Espero que pueda ser útil para alguien que esté presentando el mismo problema.